# `moxios.wait` never executes when testing VueJS with Jest, Vue Test Utils and Moxios

Tags: vue.js, moxios

I'm trying to write my first unit test for a VueJS component that grabs some data from an API endpoint when it renders:

My VueJS component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: {
          userIndexUrl: {
            required: true
          }
        },
  data() {
    userList: [],
    tableIsLoading: true
  },
  created() {
    const url = this.userIndexUrl;
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      this.userList = response.data.data;
      this.tableIsLoading = false;
    })
  },
}
```

and my test:

```
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils'
import moxios from 'moxios'
import UsersAddRemove from 'users_add_remove.vue'

describe('UsersAddRemove', () => {
  const PROPS_DATA = {
      userIndexUrl: '/users.json'
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    moxios.stubRequest('/users1.json', {
      status: 200,
      response: {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [
            { "id" : 1,
              "email" : "brayan@schaeferkshlerin.net",
              "first_name" : "Kenneth",
              "last_name" : "Connelly"
            }
          ]
        }
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('loads users from remote JSON endpoint and renders table', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(UsersAddRemove, { propsData: PROPS_DATA });
    moxios.wait(() => {
      expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<td class="">brayan@schaeferkshlerin1.net</td>');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

So what I expect to happen is the component gets instantiated, after which it does an API call, which is caught by Moxios, after which it should execute `moxios.wait`, which isn't happening. The tests seem to ignore `moxios.wait`, and it passes successfully even when it shouldn't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the `done` as argument:

```js
  it('loads users from remote JSON endpoint and renders table', (done) => {
  // -----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
    const wrapper = mount(UsersAddRemove, { propsData: PROPS_DATA });
    moxios.wait(() => {
      expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<td class="">brayan@schaeferkshlerin1.net</td>');
      done();
    });
  });
```

## Waiting for the Ajax

Change as follows:

```
// remove the stubRequest of beforeEach()
beforeEach(() => {
  moxios.install();
});

// afterEach stays the same

it('loads users from remote JSON endpoint and renders table', (done) => {
  const wrapper = mount(UsersAddRemove, { propsData: PROPS_DATA });

  moxios.wait(() => {
    let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
    request.respondWith({
      status: 200,
      response: {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [{
          "id": 1,
          "email": "brayan@schaeferkshlerin.net",
          "first_name": "Kenneth",
          "last_name": "Connelly"
        }]
      }
    }).then(function() {
      expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('<td class="">brayan@schaeferkshlerin1.net</td>');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick thanks! However, now it doesn't actually wait for the AJAX call to complete. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The thing is your own `created()` doesn't wait for the ajax request (it simply invokes it); not that I know if it *could* wait for it. I will see if you can wait until the `stubRequest` is called.

Comment: I have an idea. Don't know if it will work (can't test it), but give it a shot, would you? I added the `moxios.requests.mostRecent().then(() => {`.

Comment: Another shot. Can you try it?

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that method used in some examples, but it defies the point of creating stubRequests. Either way, I tried it and it still doesn't work. I'm beginning to think that something else may be the culprit here. You did answer the original question though!

Comment: You can try increasing the waiting time: `moxios.wait(() => { ... }, 500);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166330/discussion-between-constant-meiring-and-acdcjunior).